# I have a span that keeps disappearing once playerexp goes up by 1

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a enemy, player, bullet, and enemy has hp, after 10 damage is done player exp goes up by 1 then my /100  span disappears. Im confused why its doing this. it reappears if i relaunch the program.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/64thbvm3/

Ive tried making a maxplayerexp var and changing the span a bit but it keeps disapearing ("\100") when you kill a enemy.

code: html/javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Basic Shooter</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 4px solid #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
    <p>use the arrow keys on you keyboard to move the red square.</p>
    <span id="myEnemy1Hp">10</span> <br>
    <span id="playerExp">0<span> / <span id = "playerMaxExp">100</span> 

    <script>
        var myGamePiece;
        var endGoalPiece;
        var myEnemy1;
        var bullets = [];
        var myEnemy1Hp = 10;
        var damage = 1;
        var playerExp = 0;

        function startGame() {
            myGameArea.start();
            myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 0, 240);
            endGoalPiece = new component(30, 30, "black", 450, 240);
            myEnemy1 = new component(30, 30, "green", 200, 240);
        }

        var myGameArea = {
            canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
            start: function() {
                this.canvas.width = 480;
                this.canvas.height = 270;
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
                this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
                window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                    myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
                })
                window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                    myGameArea.key = false;
                })
            },
            clear: function() {
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            }
        }

        function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
            this.gamearea = myGameArea;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.speedX = 0;
            this.speedY = 0;
            //this.gravity = 0.05;
            //this.gravitySpeed = 0;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.color = color;
            this.update = function() {
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
            this.newPos = function() {
                this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
                this.x += this.speedX;
                this.y += this.speedY; //+ this.gravitySpeed;
                this.hitBottom();
                        this.hitTop();
                        this.hitRight();
                        this.hitLeft();
                this.hitObject();

            }
this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;

        }
        }
        this.hitTop = function() {
        var rockTop = 0;
        if (this.y < rockTop) {
            this.y = rockTop;

        }
        }
        this.hitRight = function() {
        var rockRight = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width;
        if (this.x > rockRight) {
            this.x = rockRight;

        }
        }
        this.hitLeft = function() {
        var rockLeft = 0;
        if (this.x < rockLeft) {
            this.x = rockLeft;

        }
        }

function enemyRespawn() {
        myEnemy1 = new component(30, 30, "green", 200, 240);
        myEnemy1Hp = 10;
        document.getElementById('myEnemy1Hp').innerHTML = myEnemy1Hp;
        myStopFunction();
        }



 this.hitObject = function() {
        myGamePiece.update();
        var enemy = myEnemy1.x-11;
        if (this.x == enemy) {
            myEnemy1Hp = myEnemy1Hp - damage;
            bullet= 0,0;
            document.getElementById('myEnemy1Hp').innerHTML = myEnemy1Hp;
                    if(myEnemy1Hp <=0){
            playerExp = playerExp+1;
            document.getElementById('playerExp').innerHTML = playerExp;
            myEnemy1 = new component(0, 0, "green", 0, 0);
            myEnemy1.update();
            setTimeout(enemyRespawn, 5000);

            }

                }
                }

        }

        function jump() {
            myGamePiece.gravitySpeed = -1;
        }

        function shootGun() {

            let bullet = new component(11, 5, "blue", myGamePiece.x + 27, myGamePiece.y + 13);
            bullet.newPos();
            bullet.speedX = 1;
            bullets.push( bullet );
        }


        function updateGameArea() {
            myGameArea.clear();
            myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
            myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
            if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {
                myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
            } //left
            if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {
                myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
            } //right
            if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38) {
                myGamePiece.gravitySpeed = -1;
            } //jump
            if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 32) {
                shootGun()
            } //shoot gun
            //if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }// down
            myEnemy1.update();
            endGoalPiece.update();
            myGamePiece.newPos();
            myGamePiece.update();
            bullets.forEach( (bullet)=> {
                bullet.newPos() 
                bullet.update();
            });
            // bullet.newPos();
            // bullet.update();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect when the enemy dies/ player exp goes up by 1 for the \100 span to not disappear from view. but at the moment it disappears when ever you kill a enemy.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your `<span>` you do this:

```
<span id="playerExp">0<span> / <span id = "playerMaxExp">100</span>
```

The `playerExp` span is missing a slash for its closing tag. You have `<span>` instead of `</span>`.

Change it to:

```
<span id="playerExp">0</span> / <span id="playerMaxExp">100</span>
```